# Does BFCAllocator on GPU really support host-side deallocation before GPU execution takes place?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

When I read the code of XLA in TF, I met following code snippets.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_launch_util.h#L119

```
// Adapter class that wraps a Tensorflow allocator as an XLA allocator.
// Assumes that the Tensorflow allocator permits asynchronous deallocation:
// see comment on `AllowsAsynchronousDeallocation()`.
class XlaAllocator : public xla::DeviceMemoryAllocator {
 public:
  XlaAllocator(const se::Platform* platform, Allocator* wrapped);
  ~XlaAllocator() override;
  xla::StatusOr<xla::OwningDeviceMemory> Allocate(
      int device_ordinal, uint64 size, bool retry_on_failure) override;
  Status Deallocate(int device_ordinal, se::DeviceMemoryBase mem) override;

  // The Tensorflow BFC allocator used on GPU allows host-side deallocation
  // before GPU execution takes place. Tensorflow uses the ordering of the main
  // compute stream to enforce a happens-before relationship between a memory
  // allocation and code that reuses the same memory. If Tensorflow adds
  // support for multiple GPU streams or allocators with different ordering
  // requirements, this code may need to change.
  // (This attribute has no effect on CPU.)
  bool AllowsAsynchronousDeallocation() const override { return true; }

 private:
  Allocator* wrapped_;
};
```

As shown in the comment, it said that the Tensorflow BFC allocator used on GPU allows host-side deallocation before GPU execution takes place.

This really confused me. After diving into the code of BFCAllocator, I found nothing to support this.

So my question is:

- Does Tensorflow BFC allocator really support asyn deallocation from host-side?
- If it is true, then what do I miss?

Thanks!